# Find list of collections by tags filter "OR"

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want make a filter tag system with mongoose.
The principle is simple, I have a model that has an array of string and an array in input.
I want select elements which contains tags in the input array.
Example:

```
game_console [{
    name: "Playsation",
    tags: ["old", "sony"]
}, {
    name: "xBox",
    tags: ["nintendo", "powerfull"]
}, {
    name: "megadrive",
    tags: ["old", "sega"]
}, {
    name: "Gameboy",
    tags: ["prehistory", "sega"]
}];
```

If I put in array input ["old", "sega"], I must get the elements: Playstation and Megadrive.

After searching I found `$in` and I tested that:

```
Preambule.find({
        'tags': {
            $in: tags_array_input
        }
    }).sort('-commentaires_size')
    .exec(function(err, things) {
        // [...]
    });
```

It works but only if my field tags was not an array of String..

I don't know what to search in documentation.

My model :

```
var PreambuleSchema = new Schema({
    titre: String,
    description: String,
    content: String,
    auteur: String,
    tags: [String],
    votes: [],
    commentaires: [{
        "authorMail": String,
        "content": String
    }],
    commentaires_size: Number,
    date: String
});
```

I'm using yeoman fullstacks, Angularjs, mangoose, nodeJs.

Comment: Is that a typo or is there really a mangoose and mangodb?

Comment: Maybe a error of my part. I use mangoose on a mangodb server who i manage from cmd. I must remove mangodb of my post(articl stackoverflow) because its out subject?

Comment: It sounds like `$in` is exactly what you need. It does work with array fields. `{ "tags" : { "$in" : [ a, b ] } }`, where `tags` is an array, will find all documents where at least one element of the `tags` field is `a` or is `b`. However, it's unclear exactly what you're looking for because, in the example you gave, I don't know why Gameboy shouldn't also match your criteria. Perhaps a typo? Gameboy was a Nintendo product.

Comment: Ok sorry. It was just because sometime in my filter, i enter in input one tags and that was not correct use <$in> if input it's not a array.
Thanks you guy